# NEXT.js + firebase hosting + firebase function + express application works on serve but not when deployed

Tags: javascript, express, google-cloud-functions, next.js, firebase-hosting

Following the example in Next.js repo [with-firebase-hosting sample](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-firebase-hosting).

Here is my repo https://github.com/jojonarte/with-express-firebasehosting-next

I'm trying to modify the functions server to use `express` for handling redirects.

The app works properly when deploying it locally via `firebase serve` but `firebase deploy` doesn't work as intended.

It actually deploys properly but whenever I open the deployed hosting link I get error below in `firebase console`

```
TypeError: handler is not a function
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
    at /worker/worker.js:783:7
    at /worker/worker.js:766:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```